# Prove that $\iint_{|x|+|y| \leq 1} f(x+y) \, dx \, dy = \int_{-1}^{1} f(t) \, dt$

Tags: integration

Prove:
$$\iint\limits_{|x|+|y| \leq 1} f(x+y) \, dx \, dy = \int_{-1}^{1} f(t) \, dt$$

> I suppose we need to substitute $x+y$ with $u$ and continue the job with four divided parts, but I got $\int_0^1 uf(u) \, du $ which is far from $\int_{-1}^{1} f(t) \, dt$.

Comment: Do you know about change of variables in double integrals? (For example, $u=x+y$, $v=x-y$?)

Comment: How did you get the factor $u$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$
I = \int_{|x| + |y| < 1} f(x+y) \,dx\,dy = \int_{-1<x+y<1} \int_{-1<x-y<1} f(x+y) \, dx\,dy
$$

Now use the change of variables
$$
u = x+y\\
v = x-y
$$

and get, after the jacobian computation:
$$
I =\frac 12 \int_{-1}^{1} \int_{-1}^{1}f(u) \, du \, dv
= \int_{-1}^1f(u) \, du
$$

---

Jacobian: as $x = 1/2(u+v), y = 1/2(u-v)$:

$$\frac {D(x,y)}{D(u,v)}=
\begin{vmatrix}
  1/2 & 1/2 \\
 -1/2 & 1/2
 \end{vmatrix} = 1/4 + 1/4 = 1/2
$$